# Create provisioning file for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I want my App to support Push Notification, and I do as below:

1. Generate CSR file
2. Create an App ID and enable Push Notification
3. Create Development SSL Certificate for the App ID, using CSR file created in step 1
4. Create Provisioning file

The problem is, in step 4, I cannot select the certificate created in step 3. Is there anything wrong in my steps?

Thanks.

Comment: see this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

Comment: http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/07/push-notification.html?q=push

Comment: @iAmbitious I completely followed this guide but still could not select the certificate :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't select push SSL Certificate while creating provisioning profile. Just select developer Or Distribution certificate.

Upload push SSL certificate in server that provide push service...ex: parse, arban airship. Its optional.

Comment: Please explain your answer, should we select the certificate in step 4 which is created in step 1?

Comment: in step 4 you need to select just development/distribution certificate..not push SSL.

Answer (score 3):

You can't select the SSL certificate just because you don't have to.
The provisioning profile is not related to the push certificate, but to the App ID, that's where you have set your app to use the APN service.
The SSL certificate must be uploaded on your server so it can be identified as **your** app server when making calls to Apple. You just need to download it, open it in your keychain and then usually export it and upload it on your server.

It's quite simple, just be sure to sign your app with a development provisioning profile when you are using a development push certificate on your server (making calls to apple sandbox server), and a distribution profile when you are using a production certificate.

If you are still getting problems take a look at [this guide](http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates), it's from quickblox, but the part related to the Apple portal it's the same independently form the server or the service you are using to generate notification and it's really well explained.

Answer (score 0):

follow this it might help you,
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 0):

I also followed all the tutorials mentioned above. I had the same issue with 'step 4'.

What I found out is that I cannot create a provisioning profile manually (using THE certificate). It automatically generates it for me once my Xcode **5** synchronizes with my AppId which was created by myself. So I would like to suggest that you wait a few minutes after you pressing the 'fix issue' button from the general tab. (BTW, I am new to IOS developer.)